# Yii2 Update the entry if it exists

Tags: orm, yii2, yii2-model

Item $title defined earlier. I want what if found $find_title,  update it with all fields from $title.  Otherwise, create a new object

```
  $find_title = Title::find()->where(["upc" => $title->upc])->one();
                    if ($find_title != null) {
                        $title->id = $find_title->id;
                        $title->save();
                    } else {
                        $title->save();
                    }
```

It worked in the laravel.

Answer (score 1):

```
$find_title = Title::find()->where(["upc" => $title->upc])->one();
if ($find_title != null) {
    $id = $title->id;
    $find_title->attributes = $title->attributes;
    $find_title->id = $id;
    $find_title->save();
} else {
    $title->save();
}
```

Here you assign all attributes of `$title` to `$find_title`, restore `id`, and then save;